# android bluetooth RFCOMM data transfer rate is too slow

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing an `android app` to receive `big file` (about 4M) from other hardware device. The device send data in `1382400 bps`, but my android program only receive `400K`. The data read code is in an independent thread and do nothing but read from `InputStream` and count the byte read. This is my code snippet:

```
try {
    socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_SECURE);
    socket.connect();
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int byteRead ;
    while ((byteRead = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
        totalBytes += byteRead;
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "read byte:" + totalBytes);
    }
} catch (IOExcepiton e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Connect to bluetooth device failed.", e);
    return null;
}
```

I've done lots of experiments trying to find out the problem:

1. The above code run on different Android phones(from `android 6.0` to `android 8.0`), which can receive `400K ~ 500K` of data when the sender send `4M` data. Obviously, 90% of data is lost during transmission.
2. If the sender device send a small file, no more than `2K` at the same rate, android is able to receive completely. It start to lost data after the first `2K` packet.
3. If the sender keep the same `baudrate(1382400)`, but sleep `50ms` after every `1K` transmission, android is also able to receive the entire `4M` file completely.
4. I transmit the `4M` file from one android phone to another android using the android native bluetooth share function, it takes about `30s` without data lost.

The No. 4 indicates android natively support high rate transmission (> `1Mbps`), but I cannot implement in my own code. 
The remote device use `HC-06` serial to `bluetooth` adapter which the document can be found [here](http://www.hc01.com/service_download). The document shows the adapter support `1.3M` bps rate both in serial and `bluetooth` on the air.

I searched lots of article in stackoverflow and google, no further information about android `bluetooth` transfer rate and low level `buffer` size.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to get the high transfer rate in `android`? Much thanks.

Comment: What is the current HC-06 baud rate? See the notes in chapter 9. AT Command Set in http://www.sgbotic.com/products/datasheets/wireless/hc06_datasheet.pdf. Normally in serial communication like Bluetooth, UART, USB and RS232, the source and sink must work at the same speed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524866/android-bluetooth-serial-rfcomm-low-baud-rate-slow-transmission?rq=1

Comment: I'm sure HC-06 has been set to the correct baudrate. If the baudrate is incorrect, all data will be incorrect, but in my case, the first 2K packet is complete and correct and if the sender sleep without changing the baudrate, all data is correctly received.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using a buffered stream. Reading byte by byte and printing it to a log message is way toooo slow. With this you bind the speed of the byte reading to the speed of your debug output.

This question may also be duplicate to
[Android Bluetooth Serial RFCOMM low baud rate / slow transmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524866/android-bluetooth-serial-rfcomm-low-baud-rate-slow-transmission?rq=1)

Comment: It no difference if I comment the Log. I count the total bytes after transmission is end.